# Find words in a list that start with words from another list excluding vowels

Tags: text-processing, scripting

I have two lists:

- [first one](https://www.eff.org/files/2016/07/18/eff_large_wordlist.txt) contains regular words
- [second one](https://pastebin.com/raw/CiYe9PHt) contains lines with random consonant strings (fixed length)

I need this:

- a list of only those words that start with one of the consonant strings when vowels are excluded (aeiou)
- a list of leftover, unmatched consonant strings

and this:

- some kind of key–value list of consonant strings and matching words (e.g., `fbr: foobar, foobarbaz` or whatever format is easy to further wrangle with command line tools)

The system is Cygwin and the preferred shell is Bash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example files, a few lines of each list, and the output you expect from that example. We can't help you parse data that you don't show us. Also, please tell us your operating system so we know what tools are available.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

words=(foobar foobarbaz STRING)
strings=(fbr STRN xyz)

vowels=aeiouAEIOU # adjust as needed
typeset -A matches=()
for word ($words) {
  word_without_vowels=${word//[$vowels]}
  for string ($strings)
    if [[ $word_without_vowels = $string* ]] matches[$string]+=" $word"
}
for string ($strings)
  if (( $+matches[$string] )) print -r -- "$string:$matches[$string]"
```

Gives:

```
fbr: foobar foobarbaz
STRN: STRING
```